# unable to view graphical layout while doing android application

Tags: android

i am new to android application..i am developing a application but i am unable to view graphical layout.It is showing empty.Some of my asked to open with android layout editor.Even though i open with androidlayouteditor it is not showing any graphical representation.Please help me.

thanks and regards,
pradeep kovvuru

Comment: I assume that you have an error in your layout, due to which your layout does not render. Can you please show your layout xml?

Comment: hello dimitris,
  i am unable to add the xml file to this....its a large one please make me to choose an alternative...thanks..or else i can mail it to u if you give me chance 
thanks & regards pradeep k